# How do I properly deprecate Gutenberg block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have a custom Gutenberg block (https://pastebin.com/bV2k5Ekc) in which I display text, link and an image. I want to change it so so instead of saving the image URL as a background image of the container, to use an img tag. Unfortunately - I can't manage to create the deprecation correctly - I fail at assigning the attributes parameters in the deprecation:

From this:

```
    const {
      attributes: {
        mediaURL,
        boxTitle,
        boxDescription,
        linkText,
        linkHref,
        linkTitle
      },
      className,
    } = props;

    let boxClass = 'cta-box';
    let contentDescription = '';

    if (boxDescription.length) {
      boxClass += ' cta-box-description';
      contentDescription = (
        <p>
          {boxDescription}
        </p>
      )
    }

    return (
      <div className={`cta-block-box ${className}`}>
        <a
          className="cta-box-link"
          href={linkHref}
          style={{ backgroundImage: "url(" + mediaURL + ")" }}
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          <div className={boxClass}>
            <h3>
              {boxTitle}
            </h3>
            {contentDescription}
            <span className="arrow">{linkText ? linkText : linkTitle}</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  },
```

To this (I only change what's in the return statement):

```
return (
      <div className={`cta-block-box ${className}`}>
        <a
          className="cta-box-link"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          <img className="cta-box-image" src={linkHref} alt=""/>
          <div className={boxClass}>
            <h3>
              {boxTitle}
            </h3>
            {contentDescription}
            <span className="arrow">{linkText ? linkText : linkTitle}</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    );
```

Which of course broke the Gutenberg element. So I added a deprecate to the blog, as much as I could following the official Wordpress documentation:

```
deprecated: [
    {
      attributes: {...this.attributes},
      save: (props) => {
        const {
          attributes: {
            mediaURL,
            boxTitle,
            boxDescription,
            linkText,
            linkHref,
            linkTitle
          },
          className,
        } = props;
        console.log('dep');
        console.log(props);

        let boxClass = 'cta-box';
        let contentDescription = '';

        if (boxDescription.length) {
          boxClass += ' cta-box-description';
          contentDescription = (
            <p>
              {boxDescription}
            </p>
          )
        }

        return (
          <div className={`cta-block-box ${className}`}>
            <a
              className="cta-box-link"
              style={{ backgroundImage: "url(" + mediaURL + ")" }}
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              <div className={boxClass}>
                <h3>
                  {boxTitle}
                </h3>
                {contentDescription}
                <span className="arrow">{linkText ? linkText : linkTitle}</span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        );
      },
    }
  ],
```

After this the editor page crashes, and I get error message in console, that attributes is not defined (displaying incorrect row in the script file). This is the "after" script contents (https://pastebin.com/dVdLMx7N).

```
react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:125 ReferenceError: attributes is not defined
    at save (cta-box2.js?f66a:242)
    at Wt (blocks.min.js?ver=9ed25ffa009c799f99a4340915b6dc6a:3)
    at Qt (blocks.min.js?ver=9ed25ffa009c799f99a4340915b6dc6a:3)
    at block-editor.min.js?ver=4378547cec8f5157a02ead3dfc5c65b2:12
    at hooks.min.js?ver=50e23bed88bcb9e6e14023e9961698c1:2
    at $r (blocks.min.js?ver=9ed25ffa009c799f99a4340915b6dc6a:3)
    at blocks.min.js?ver=9ed25ffa009c799f99a4340915b6dc6a:3
    at Ur (blocks.min.js?ver=9ed25ffa009c799f99a4340915b6dc6a:3)
    at blocks.min.js?ver=9ed25ffa009c799f99a4340915b6dc6a:3
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I suspect I'm missing some small detail, but so far I've failed to locate it. And was not able to find relevant enough information on the web.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The trick with deprecation functions is you basically copy _exactly_ what you had in `save` function before. Same with the attributes. They need to be _exactly_ what they were in the previous version of the block.

Comment: @Phil, that's what I generally did. The thing that confused me is that the attributes were not passed to the deprecation, or I'm unable to initialize them there. I do not change any of the attributes - I use the same values, just change the way they are interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in [your "after" script](https://pastebin.com/dVdLMx7N):

1. The attributes do not match (and the `this` is actually the `window` object): `attributes: {...this.attributes}` (see line 212).

   So what you used with the `attributes` property on line 24, should also be used with the same property on line 212. (because you only changed the output, so the block attributes remain the same)
2. The `save` output/markup also do not match — in the "before" script, you've got `href={linkHref}`, but in the *`deprecated` property* of the "after" script, the `save` output did not have that `href`. [(see this diff)](https://www.diffchecker.com/aKnLQHuA)

So make sure the attributes and `save` output match the ones in the old/"before" script, and the following is how your code would look like, but note that I only included the main parts that need to be fixed:

```js
// Define the attributes and use it with the root "attributes" property and
// the one in the "deprecated" property.
const blockAttributes = {
  mediaID: {
    type: 'number'
  },
  mediaURL: {
    type: 'string'
  },
  boxTitle: {
    type: 'string',
    default: ''
  },
  // ... the rest of the attributes here.
};

registerBlockType('hswp/test-box', {
  title: __('Test Box', 'modula'),
  // ... your code.
  attributes: blockAttributes,
  // ... your code.
  deprecated: [
    {
      attributes: blockAttributes,
      save: (props) => {
        // ... your code.

        return (
          <div className={`cta-block-box ${className}`}>
            <a
              className="cta-box-link"
              href={linkHref}
              style={{ backgroundImage: "url(" + mediaURL + ")" }}
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              ... your code.
            </a>
          </div>
        );
      },
    }
  ],
});
```

Additionally, note that the [`PlainText` component](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/plain-text) doesn't (as of writing) have a property named `tagName`.

Comment: Thank you! 
The lacking href was mainly a problem with trying to reproduce the issue, as I worked around the original problem in another way (time of delivery was pressing).
The main problem with my approach was that it did not occur to me that I can initialize the attributes outside of registerBlockType, and thus was having problems getting to them. With your proposed solution the block works and I managed to successfully create a block with the old version, change the code, and when I saved again the block - it worked!
https://pastebin.com/MvdGWx3P